# How to find the nodes of a cluster from the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I would like to use wmic in my batch file to find the nodes of the cluster. I have found various references to the `MSCluster_Node` class, but I can't seem to get this working from the wmic command. I have tried the following command:

```
wmic /node:"clustername" Path MSCluster_Node
```

But if gives the following error message:

> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid class

Answer (score -1):

I found that the MSCluster_Nodes class is not in the default namespace. To change the namespace in wmic, use the `/namespace:` switch.

After a certain amount of trial and error, I found that this works:

```
wmic /node:"clustername" /namespace:\\root\MSCluster Path MSCluster_Node
```